# CoreData+RESTKit: Multiple copies of same object from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using the same NSFetchedResultsController to grab some results from core data backed by sqllite through RESTKit that are shared between multiple view controllers:

```
NSFetchedResultsController* _fetchedResultsController;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"username" ascending:YES]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"current == YES"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
_fetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:[self __getContext]
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"currentUser"];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:error];
NSArray *array = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
return array;
```

This is called at multiple stages during app execution, however despite the fact that I specify a cache name, I get multiple copies of the same object i.e. not a single source of truth.

This issue only occurs on reload of the app. Not a problem on initial mapping of the objects.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Edit:

First some context:

I mark the currently logged in user with a current attribute, and any view controllers that need access to the current user will execute the cached fetch request.

At some point early in the app, one view controller adds itself as an observer to the current user that is received from this fetch request. At another point in the apps execution, the user creates an album at which point the fetch request is executed again. This time the memory address of the object is different, and the first view controller doesn't receive a KVO notification when the album is added to the users set attribute.

Here are some extra logs that show that RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache starts returning a different User object:

```
2014-02-15 16:15:53.196 [22074:a0b] user init: 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> in context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xf079790>
2014-02-15 16:15:53.198 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.209 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.209 [22074:a0b] [AlbumCollectionViewController] observing user 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2>: robbie
2014-02-15 16:15:53.209 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.262 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.262 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.269 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.269 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf090b60 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.278 [22074:a0b] applicationDidBecomeActive
2014-02-15 16:15:53.329 [22074:a0b] user init: 0xf342590 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> in context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xf079790>
2014-02-15 16:15:53.329 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf342590 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.329 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf342590 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.346 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf342590 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
2014-02-15 16:15:53.348 [22074:a0b] [<RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache: 0xf0593b0>] In memory object cache is returning 0xf342590 <x-coredata://56C4885F-954C-4843-9A59-52133777ECC5/User/p2><robbie> as current user
```

It always seems to start returning something different once applicationDidBecomeActive is called, strangely.

Edit2:

Call stack leading up to first User init:

```
#0  0x000e87f0 in -[User initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/CoreData/Human/User.m:107
#1  0x00f68a89 in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _initWithEntity:withID:withHandler:withContext:] ()
#2  0x00f66ff2 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] ()
#3  0x00fb69b4 in _PFRetainedObjectIDCore ()
#4  0x00fb6880 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:] ()
#5  0x00fa7724 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] ()
#6  0x010251f4 in __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke ()
#7  0x00fa7321 in internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#8  0x035fb4b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#9  0x035e8778 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#10 0x035e8422 in dispatch_barrier_sync_f ()
#11 0x00fa72a2 in _perform ()
#12 0x00fa714e in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#13 0x00f526c6 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
#14 0x00276367 in __96-[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache managedObjectsWithEntity:attributeValues:inManagedObjectContext:]_block_invoke_2 at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:112
#15 0x00fa6fef in developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#16 0x00fa6f2c in -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] ()
#17 0x00275ce4 in -[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache managedObjectsWithEntity:attributeValues:inManagedObjectContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:109
#18 0x000d73d9 in -[RestKitInterface getCurrentUsersWithError:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/RESTKit/Old/RestKitInterface.m:647
#19 0x000e9613 in +[User currentUser] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/CoreData/Human/User.m:221
#20 0x0002f6f0 in -[TabBarController viewWillAppear:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/View Controllers/AppTabBarController.m:100
```

Call stack leading up to second user init:

```
#0  0x000e87f0 in -[User initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/CoreData/Human/User.m:107
#1  0x00f68a89 in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _initWithEntity:withID:withHandler:withContext:] ()
#2  0x00f66ff2 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] ()
#3  0x00fb69b4 in _PFRetainedObjectIDCore ()
#4  0x00f7ffbf in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:error:] ()
#5  0x00f7fef5 in -[NSManagedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:error:] ()
#6  0x0025e29a in __56-[RKEntityByAttributeCache objectForObjectID:inContext:]_block_invoke at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityByAttributeCache.m:222
#7  0x00fa6fef in developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
#8  0x00fa6f2c in -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] ()
#9  0x0025dd7c in -[RKEntityByAttributeCache objectForObjectID:inContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityByAttributeCache.m:221
#10 0x0025ea74 in -[RKEntityByAttributeCache objectsWithAttributeValues:inContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityByAttributeCache.m:255
#11 0x00265644 in -[RKEntityCache objectsForEntity:withAttributeValues:inContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityCache.m:90
#12 0x00275f15 in -[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache managedObjectsWithEntity:attributeValues:inManagedObjectContext:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:132
#13 0x000d73d9 in -[RestKitInterface getCurrentUsersWithError:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/RESTKit/Old/RestKitInterface.m:647
#14 0x000e9613 in +[User currentUser] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/CoreData/Human/User.m:221
#15 0x00003efb in -[AlbumCollectionViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] at /Users/mtford/Playground/App/App/App/View Controllers/AlbumCollectionViewController.m:179
```

Comment: Can you show example duplicates, how are you checking / comparing them?

Comment: Hi Wain, Added to the question.

Comment: I did some more investigation and it seems that the in memory object cache creates a brand new object after applicationDidBecomeActive is called. Not sure whether thats a coincidence...

Comment: Any requests made with RestKit during your scenario? Identification attributes configured in RestKit? And where are these log coming from (what creates the new user)?

Comment: No requests are made with RestKit, everything loaded purely from sqlite. I've placed the call stacks leading up to `[User init]` in the question. You can see that RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache is involved in both, whereas I believe it should only be creating one instance of this. Identification attributes are indeed configured. The object cache maps correctly onto the 2nd created user from this point forward, using the identification attributes.

Comment: Are those 2 blocks of code running on different threads? It appears to be 2 different managed object instances both backed by the same underlying entity data.

Comment: They're both on the main thread. I'm at a loss here...

Answer (score 0):

In our project with RESTKit and CoreData we also get same duplication issue, easiest way to avoid duplication is setting unique id param to entity mapping with `setIdentificationAttributes`

Comment: Check the comments, OP has identification attributes and does no mapping during the problem scenario...